# EmberJS - Get controller created in {{render}} helper

Tags: ember.js

I have a {{render 'B' model}} helper in template A, so B/BView/BController are essentially children of A/AView/AController.  BController even has AController as its parentController.

Is there a way to (easily) reference BController from AController? I'd prefer not to set something to B's parentController because it's not always A.

Answer (score 1):

Ember lets you use a `needs` property for this purpose: http://emberjs.com/guides/controllers/dependencies-between-controllers/

```
App.AController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    needs: ['b']
    actions: {
        somethingWithA: function() {
            var bController= this.get('controllers.b');
            // ...
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: This will not give me a reference to the specific instance of the controller: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/xiqiqebopohi/1/edit